# How can I create a movable and resizable polygon with over 1000 sides/lines?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, polygons

Right now I'm using UIBezierPath and `moveToPoint`/`addLineToPoint` inside a view's `drawRect`. 
This same view receives `touchesMoved` from the viewController. It modifies the `posx` and `posy` variables that are used when I draw the polygon, like this:

```
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake([p.getx floatValue]+posx, [p.gety floatValue]+posy)]
```

Unfortunately the performance is horrible and the polygon leaves a trail whenever I move it.

What's the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

edit: the drawRect. `polys` is a NSMutableArray with `poly` objects. Each poly is one x/y point.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
UIBezierPath* path;
UIColor* fillColor;
path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
for (int i = 0; i < [polys count]; i++){
    poly *p = [polys objectAtIndex:i];
    if (i == 0){
        [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake([p.getx floatValue]+posx, [p.gety floatValue]+posy)];
    }else{
        [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake([p.getx floatValue]+posx, [p.gety floatValue]+posy)];
        fillColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // plan to use a random color here
        }
    }
[path closePath];
[fillColor setFill];
[path fill];
}
```

Comment: Can you post a bit more code? The whole `drawRect` method?

Comment: Yes I can. Just edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't figured out your problem. My guess is that you want to draw the polygon with user's finger. I have this small class that works perfectly, probably it can help:

```
@implementation View {
    NSMutableArray* _points;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    _points = [NSMutableArray array];

    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Clear old path
    [_points removeAllObjects];

    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];

    [_points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p]];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];

    [_points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p]];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    for (int i = 0; i < _points.count; i++){
        CGPoint p = [_points[i] CGPointValue];
        if (i == 0){
            [path moveToPoint:p];
        }
        else {
            [path addLineToPoint:p];
        }
    }

    [path closePath];

    UIColor* color = [UIColor blueColor];
    [color setFill];
    [path fill];
}

@end
```

Just add the view somewhere in your app, maybe make it full screen.

Comment: The polygon is already built. I want the use to be able to move and resize (pinch) it. However I have about 60 polygons with over 1000 sides each. Performance is horrible when I try to move it.

Comment: Hmm that adds up to 60000 sides... How about converting each polygon into a bitmap and scale / rotate / translate it?

Comment: That'd be great. Is there a method that converts the polygon into a bitmap automatically? do you know of any tutorials that explain how to do it?

Comment: You can start by creating an image with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, acquiring the `CGContextRef` with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`. Drawing on the image is can be done with [Core Graphics functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html). After drawing you can extract the `UIImage*` with `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`. It will involve a fair bit of maths to figure out the size of the image, and the offset to each point.

Comment: Not sure if you are familiar with Core Graphics (aka Quartz 2D), but it's similar to what you have done with your code, just at a lower level. If you're interested, have a look at [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html), maybe on the *Path* section for your problem.

Comment: I'm not, but I'll look into it. It's faster, but openGL would be even faster right?

Comment: I haven't used OpenGL on iOS so I can't say. But you have to turn them in to images anyway since 60000 sides are still too much even for OpenGL.